# How is it possible to get more than 6 reviewer Badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

Reviewer is a silver badge which is awarded once per review type.

So, the maximum number of reviewer badge should be 6, but I saw some users having more than 6.

How is it possible?

is there any other way to gain that badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the old system, you got the review badge if you had 1000 reviews with over 200 actioned. This badge was not revoked with the new system.

If you see the reviewer badges in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer?userid=18061), you see the first had the description '1000 reviews, over 200 actioned in the old review system '.

Comment: we can see many users having more than 6 reviewer badges, bcas of dis reason